# Update Magento 2.3.4 to 2.3.5-p2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

[image]

Facing Error whilst updating Magento 2.3.4 to 2.3.5-p2 on Home Page

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Filter\DateTime

Comment: It may be a permission issue so it not allow to generate file try sudo chmod -Rv 777 app/ pub/ generated/ var/ it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing var/viewpreprocessed, var/cache, var/page_cache, /generated, pub/static/frontend, and pub/static/adminhtml.

Then run setup:upgrade, and change the mode to production mode (php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production)